# Azure CLI - How to add Tags to Azure Sql server (logical server)?

Tags: sql-server, tags, azure-cli

When trying to script the Tags creation for a SQL server (Logical server) in Azure not sure which command should be used.
The az sql server create does not have the option to send the tags as parameters.
I'm trying to use az resource tag but is not finding the resource type.
I've got the resource type when executing az sql server show.

I've tried the following commands:

```
az resource tag --tags Project=$PROJECTNAME Owner=$OWNERNAME Function=$FUNCTIONNAME -g $RESOURCEGROUPNAME -n $SQLSERVERNAME --resource-type "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases"

az resource --subscription $SubscriptionName tag --tags Project=$PROJECTNAME Owner=$OWNERNAME Function=$FUNCTIONNAME -g $RESOURCEGROUPNAME -n $SQLSERVERNAME --resource-type "Microsoft.Sql/servers"
```

Results are always: 
Operation failed with status: 'Not Found'. Details: Resource not found for the segment 'servers'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested the command, it works. Make sure you use the **correct resource group** which contains your sql server.

```
az resource tag --tags Project=test1 Owner=test2 Function=test3 -g $resourceGroupname -n $serverName --resource-type "Microsoft.Sql/servers/"
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Tony,
Thanks for the reply.
When executing the command as you suggested the following error is appearing:
Operation failed with status: 'Not Found'. Details: Resource not found for the segment 'servers'.
I'm using a SQL Server (logical server). Which server type did you use in your example?

Comment: I was sending server name in CAPS and it should be in in low caps.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to user the command Tony Ju solution to tag the database server, however was not able to use it to tag the database. I ended up using the following command. (by using the resource ID)

`az resource tag --tags Project=test1 Owner=test2 Function=test3 --ids /subscriptions/{subscription ID}/resourceGroups/{resource group}/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/{sql server}/databases/{database}`